# What's the best way to align nested divs to parent divs and text inside divs?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I made this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cRmCc/2/ and I was wondering what would be the best way to vertically and horizontally align nested divs inside a parent div with out using margin or padding. More preferably the exact center. I'll be using this as a reference and Google isn't that much of a help. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
        Some Text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.container2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Searching for *css vertical align* or *css vertical center* brings up no useful results?  I am surprised...  http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` along with `text-align:center;` and `display:inline-block;`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRmCc/3/)

```
.container1 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;    
}
.container2 {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Note: You will need a fallback for older browsers, if supported.